# How to Downgrade/Revert 'was resolved to' Specific Pod Repo Version?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

After get latest from team's git, I'm getting this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AppsFlyerFramework":
In Podfile:
AppsFlyerFramework (~> 5.2.0)

react-native-appsflyer (from `../node_modules/react-native-appsflyer`)
was resolved to 5.4.40, which depends on AppsFlyerFramework (~> 5.4.4)

Specs satisfying the `AppsFlyerFramework (~> 5.2.0), AppsFlyerFramework (~> 5.4.4)`
dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I cannot go to 5.4.4, so how to revert that was resolved to 5.4.40 back to 5.2.0? Deleted podfile.lock but no luck.